# Images in iCloud for my Messages app will not download completely

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, messages, messages-in-icloud

At some point, I agreed for iOS to store images from Messages in iCloud to free up space on my iPhone X. That is, the images are deleted from the conversations in Messages, and have to be downloaded from iCloud if you want them to reappear in the conversation. I have 20GB available, but Messages still stores images from recent messages in iCloud. I don't mind that behavior, but I cannot always download them again.

For instance, pick a conversation in Messages, tap the contact at the top of the conversation, then tap info. Here you will see the photos from within the conversation. Scrolling down, there is an option to download images from iCloud. When I tap download I do not get the images downloaded onto my phone again.

I would like to prevent the removal of images from my conversations, but I cannot find an option in the settings. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?